# Divide a list into two lists one from minimum to maximum and the other from maximum to minimum

Tags: python

I have two lists as given below;

```
phi= [0,pi/4, pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi, 5*pi/4, 3*pi/2, 7*pi/4, 2*pi]
t = [1,1.25,1.50,1.25,1,0.75,0.5,0.5,0.75]
```

I get `t` from computation of the `phi` list. So `phi = 0` gives me `t = 1` and so on. I want two lists from `t` and two from `phi`. First list will start from the minimum value of `t` (at second last position) to maximum value of `t`. The `phi` list will be the `phi` values associated with those new `t` values. Second list of `t` values will start from the maximum `t` value and end at the minimum. Second `phi` list should be the `phi` values associated with this `t` value lists. Is there a way to code this?

Desired Output:

```
t1 = [0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5];    phi1 = [7*pi/4, 2*pi, 0, pi/4, pi/2]   
t2 = [1.50,1.25,1,0.75,0.5,];  phi2 = [pi/2, 3*pi/4, pi, 5*pi/4, 3*pi/2]
```

Comment: Could you please edit the question to add the two desired output lists? The first list for example, should be from phi=3pi/2 _backward_ to pi/2 or _forward_ (assuming that 2pi is 0 again)?

Comment: pi/2 is in both `phi1` and `phi2`, sshould the same happen with 3pi/2? Or this should not happen with 3pi/2 like it seems in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from the following data:

```
phi= ['0','pi/4', 'pi/2','3*pi/4', 'pi','5*pi/4','3*pi/2','7*pi/4', '2*pi']
t = [1,1.25,1.50,1.25,1,0.75,0.5,0.5,0.75]
```

You can get the indexes where there is the maximum and the minimum with [`numpy.argmax()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html#numpy.argmax) and [`numpy.argmin()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) which return the index of the maximum or minimum in a given list or array (note that in the case of multiple occurrences, it returns the index of the *first* extreme). Thus:

```
max_index = np.argmax(t)
min_index = np.argmin(t)
# the +1 in some indexes is to have pi/2 and 3pi/2 in both phi1 and phi2
phi1 = phi[min_index:]+phi[:max_index+1]
t1 = t[min_index:]+t[:max_index+1]
phi2 = phi[max_index:min_index+1]
t2 = t[max_index:min_index+1]
# Out: t1, phi1
# [0.5, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5] ['3*pi/2', '7*pi/4', '2*pi', '0', 'pi/4', 'pi/2']
# t2,phi2
# [1.5, 1.25, 1, 0.75, 0.5] ['pi/2', '3*pi/4', 'pi', '5*pi/4', '3*pi/2']
```

Using `numpy` may be an overkill, in which case, the `max_index` and `min_index` can be defined with built-in functions:

```
max_val = max(t)
min_val = min(t)
max_index = t.index(max_val)
min_index = t.index(min_val)
```

The same indexes are retrieved, and thus, the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Your phi list is confusing and not in proper python object form, correct it, If i am getting right then you want something like this ,

```
from math import pi
phi= phi= [0,pi/4, pi/2,3,pi/4, pi,5,pi/4,3,pi/2,7,pi/4]

t = [1,1.25,1.50,1.25,1,0.75,0.5,0.5,0.75]

zipped_=[i for i in zip(t,phi)]

print(sorted(zipped_))
print(sorted(zipped_,reverse=True))
```

output:

```
[(0.5, 0.7853981633974483), (0.5, 5), (0.75, 3), (0.75, 3.141592653589793), (1, 0), (1, 0.7853981633974483), (1.25, 0.7853981633974483), (1.25, 3), (1.5, 1.5707963267948966)]
#First list will start from the minimum value of t(at second last position) to maximum value of t.The phi list will be the phi values associated with those new t values


[(1.5, 1.5707963267948966), (1.25, 3), (1.25, 0.7853981633974483), (1, 0.7853981633974483), (1, 0), (0.75, 3.141592653589793), (0.75, 3), (0.5, 5), (0.5, 0.7853981633974483)]
#Second list of t values will start from the maximum t value and end at the minimum. second phi list should be the phi values associated with this t value lists.
```

you can change your phi list if the modified list is not same as you have.

Comment: I think that phi is an angle in radians, from 0 to 2pi in steps of pi/4